# moment.js String + Formats not working as expected

Tags: node.js, momentjs

Referring to the documentation of moment.js [String + Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) I expected these two lines to return the same date object:

```
moment('12.05.1989', ['DD.MM.YYYY','YYYY-MM-DD']);
moment('1989-05-12', ['DD.MM.YYYY','YYYY-MM-DD']);
```

However, what I get is this for the first date:

```
{ _i: '12.05.1989',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  _l: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _a:
   [ 12,
     4,
     19,
     0,
     0,
     0,
     0 ],
  _d: Sat May 19 12 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
  _isValid: true }
```

While the second is correct:

```
{ _i: '1989-05-12',
  _f: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  _l: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _a:
   [ 1989,
     4,
     12,
     0,
     0,
     0,
     0 ],
  _d: Fri May 12 1989 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Summer Time),
  _isValid: true }
```

When I change the order of the formats in the array, it is exactly the other way around, it uses the last format in array.

What am I doing wrong?

I want to avoid workarounds like checking the string for "-" or ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) states:

> The parser ignores non-alphanumeric characters, so both of the
>   following will return the same thing.

```
moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
moment("12\25\1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

In your case, it will match `12.05.1989` against your last pattern (`YYYY-MM-DD`) and parse it as *"day 1989 of the 5th month of the year 12"* (and truncates the day because it otherwise doesn't make sense).

I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening, though, so it might require you to normalize your date formats:

```
> '12.05.1989'.replace(/(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})/, '$3-$2-$1')
'1989-05-12'
```

Comment: But look at the example from the docs: `moment("12-25-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "YYYY-MM-DD"]);` - if you were right, wouldn't that take 12th year, 25th month, 1995th day...? +1 for the regex anyway :)

Comment: @ToniTornado try that with `12-01-1995`, that is parsed wrong as well. Apparently `moment` knows that in your example, there is no 25th month, and will use the first pattern instead. I don't know why it won't accept invalid months but *will* accept invalid days.